# Good alternative to this diagram tool https://github.com/francoislaberge/diagrams?

Tags: osx, diagram

I am currently using this diagram package (https://github.com/francoislaberge/diagrams) to create a sequence diagram.

It fits my work flow because I want to be able to generate a sequence diagram by running a command.

```
 diagrams sequence <my file>
```

However it misses a few features such as supporting `loop`.

Is there any good cli tool to generate sequence diagram?

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't beat [MSC generator](https://sites.google.com/site/mscgen2393/). It is cross-platform, full featured and well supported (Zoltan generally replies very quickly to emails requesting support or new features).

It takes its input from a plain text file:

[image]

Read the excellent [user mnaual](http://msc-generator.sourceforge.net/help/6.3/msc-gen.pdf) and search for "loop".

Comment: Did you try this? Doe sit meet your needs? If so, please accept the answer in order to help others who read the question in future. If not, please explain why and you might get a better response.